# text editor cuts off if you use a double space

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using TINYMCE text editor and if you use a double space the string gets cut off.  So if I write:
a a a  a -- it will output as -- a a a -- since there's a double space after the third a.  I tried:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[ ]+/', ' ', $text);
```

Which doesn't work and I set:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

This is sooo weird... what would cause this?  Thank you
**UPDATE**

Here's the code still not working...

jQuery / Ajax

```
    $('#page_left_comment_submit').click(function() {

        var comment = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); // This how you retrieve data with TINYMCE


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '........',
            data: 'comment=' + comment,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#music_spot_comment_result_all_holder_top')..html(data);

                }
            });
        });
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['comment'])) {
            $comment = $_POST['comment'];
            $comment = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $comment);

            echo $comment;

            }
```

Var dump After
This is a a a (double space) a

```
string(9) "
a a a "
```

Before

 Same string as above

```
string(9) "
a a a "
```

**UPDATE**
I'm doing this in the javascript to eliminate double spaces:

```
var comment = comment.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression for `whitespace` is `\s`.

In your case:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text);
```

Comment: preg_replace('/[ ]+/', '\\s', $_POST['comment'])?  is that it cause it doesn't work...

Comment: How does stackoverflow do it since they by default only allow single spaces?

Comment: I got Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g' in /home/content.........

Comment: @Graham my bad, remove the `g`. `g` is the modifier for global replace but `preg_replace` replaces all the occurrences by default.

Comment: It's still not working.  I'm sending it VIA ajax, I don't know if that matters.  But, I echo the string through javascript it's fine.  Once it hits the PHP is cut's off after the first occurence of a 'double space'.  You can see the update for the code...

Comment: Updated again you can see the jQuery and PHP.  It's a super simple AJAX call.  It's just the PHP when it goes haywire...

Comment: It's still not working.  Everything in the string after a double space is cut off.  It's just ignoring the regular expression.  You can even see I have the regular expression before I echo out the string.

Comment: is there a way to eliminate the double space VIA javascript?  Sorry if it's a whole new topic

Comment: @Graham post a `var_dump($comment)` before and after the replace.

Comment: Updated, it's the same before and after, so it must be ignored.  But you can see it's placed in the code...

Comment: @Graham hmm, I think the problem resides elsewhere. You can check the  working solution here `http://codepad.org/Zu7alHNt`.

Comment: It has to have something to do with the fact that it's a WYSIWYG editor.  Different rules seem to apply for manipulating data because your draft works outside of the editor.  You can see how I have to retrieve the data in the code.  You can't simply retrieve it as a variable.  So, I think you need weird hacks to mess with these editors...